# Adding Web API Search filter

Tags: php, html, xml, api

I want to add two searchers for the date and sub id above the table by API request

This is my php code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('https://partners.sites.com/affiliates/api/1/reports.asmx/Conversions?api_key=aaaaaaaaa&%20affiliate_id=11111&start_date=06/01/2019+00:00:00&end_date=06/31/2019+00:00:00&conversion_id=&subid_3&include_tests=false&start_at_row=1&row_limit=200'.$_GET["callsign"], 0, TRUE);
?>

<body>
<table class="outer">
 <table class="middle">
  <table class="inner">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>DATE</th>
      <th>NAMA OFFER</th>
      <th>NEGARA</th>
      <th>PAYOUT</th>
      <th>USER</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<?php foreach ($xml->conversions->conversion as $datanya) :?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $datanya->conversion_date; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $datanya->offer_name; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $datanya->country; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $datanya->price_usd; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $datanya->subid_3; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
   </table>
  </table>
 </table>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

[The table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NnuC.png)

and are there other ways such as filtering results that have become tables?

Comment: Hmm.. Add two input fields + button, JS which catch event from button and value and based on value set date in your API request ?

Comment: yes, that's it. sorry my english bad

Comment: You could add a jQuery datatable plugin to your page (https://datatables.net/) this will sort, paginate and search fields for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap

to Search the Api Result:

**Demo**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css
">
</head>


<?php
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement('https://partners.sites.com/affiliates/api/1/reports.asmx/Conversions?api_key=aaaaaaaaa&%20affiliate_id=11111&start_date=06/01/2019+00:00:00&end_date=06/31/2019+00:00:00&conversion_id=&subid_3&include_tests=false&start_at_row=1&row_limit=200'.$_GET["callsign"], 0, TRUE);
?>

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>DATE</th>
      <th>NAMA OFFER</th>
      <th>NEGARA</th>
      <th>PAYOUT</th>
      <th>USER</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

<?php foreach ($xml->conversions->conversion as $datanya) :?>
    <tr>
      <td><?php echo $datanya->conversion_date; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $datanya->offer_name; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $datanya->country; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $datanya->price_usd; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $datanya->subid_3; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
  </tbody>
   </table>
  </table>
 </table>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```